# Excel Office Script setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I want to recalculate an Excel worksheet every 1 second using Office Script.  Here is my failed attempt.

```js
function sendMessage(sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet) {
  console.log('hi');
  sheet.calculate(true);
}

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    setInterval(sendMessage, 1000, sheet);
}
```

Nothing printed at the console and there is no recalculation.

Answer (score 3):

I helped develop the Office Script runtime.

Generally, Office Scripts are designed to execute a sequence of steps and complete. i.e. Office Scripts aren't designed to continually run in the background.

Currently `setInterval` won't work due to how Office Scripts are executed, additionally only a single Office Script can execute at a time.

Generally, I wouldn't recommend continually running an Office Script (the runtime isn't designed to support it).

That said,

I have used busy waiting in the past to create a delay, which you could use to pause between calls. See `sleep` function below:

https://github.com/wandyezj/office-script/blob/main/functions/sleep.ts

```js
function sleep(seconds: number) {

  const millisecondDelay = seconds * 1000
  const start = Date.now()
  let now = Date.now();

  while((now - start) < millisecondDelay) {
    now = Date.now();
    // busy wait
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I used your code by declaring `async function main` and `await sheet.calculate(true);`  The complete code is shown in my answer to my post.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `sleep` provided by @wandyezj.  Here is the code.

```
function sleep(seconds: number) {
    const millisecondDelay = seconds * 1000
    const start = Date.now()
    let now = Date.now();

    while ((now - start) < millisecondDelay) {
        now = Date.now();
        // busy wait
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { }
    }
}

async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        await sheet.calculate(true);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `offise-js`, but following general principles I can guess what the `sheet` variable have no proper value on the timer event. You need to define it globally (if possible) or get the sheet inside `sendMessage`.